# Pcapy streaming to Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask, streaming, packet-capture, flask-socketio

The following script has been circling around a lot of my pcapy google searches, it does exactly what I need it to do, which is live packet capture.

```
import pcapy
from impacket.ImpactDecoder import *

# list all the network devices
pcapy.findalldevs()

max_bytes = 1024
promiscuous = False
read_timeout = 100 # in milliseconds
pc = pcapy.open_live("name of network device to capture from", max_bytes, promiscuous, read_timeout)

pc.setfilter('tcp')

# callback for received packets
def recv_pkts(hdr, data):
  packet = EthDecoder().decode(data)
  print packet

packet_limit = -1 # infinite
pc.loop(packet_limit, recv_pkts) # capture packets
```

I want to stream the results into web ui through flask. Let's use part of the example script that comes with Flask (app.py). Which is the following:

```
import threading
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room, \
    close_room, rooms, disconnect
import pcapy
from impacket.ImpactDecoder import *
from threading import Lock
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
    socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)
    thread = None
    thread_lock = Lock()


    def background_thread():
        """Example of how to send server generated events to clients."""
        count = 0
        while True:
            socketio.sleep(10)
            count += 1
            socketio.emit('my_response',
                          {'data': 'Server generated event', 'count': **INSERT STREAMING VARIABLE HERE**},
                          namespace='/test')


    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)


    @socketio.on('my_ping', namespace='/test')
    def ping_pong():
        emit('my_pong')


    @socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
    def test_connect():
        global thread
        with thread_lock:
            if thread is None:
                thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread)
        emit('my_response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})


    @socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
    def test_disconnect():
        print('Client disconnected', request.sid)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=4000)
```

where it says **INSERT STREAMING VARIABLE HERE** is where pcapy results are supposed to stream to.
For both of these to run concurrently I used threading:

```
bt = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background_thread)
rp = threading.Thread(name='', target=recv_pkts)

bt.start()
rp.start()
```

I want to see Pcapy results streamed into Flask but I have no idea how to do it. Please help!